# *** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot *** but it never is; remedy?

Tags: linux-mint, fsck, root-filesystem

System: [Linux Mint 19 "Tara" - Cinnamon (64-bit)](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=254), based on Ubuntu 18.04, kernel `5.3.0-24-generic`

---

Problem duration: 1 month.

Problem description: since this computer malfunctioned before my intervention, it comes to no surprise, that every time I `ssh` to this machine, I get this message:

```
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
```

---

in spite, that in `/etc/fstab` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab)) I do have `1` as a file system check:

```
UUID=03b1e8ee-9ad8-4afa-a4ca-xxxxxxxxxxxx  /  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

and in spite in `/etc/default/grub` ([man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html)) the check is forced:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes"
```

---

What more can I / do I need to do to actually force the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably had something to do with disk settings, because after:

---

#### Disk time interval check

```
sudo tune2fs -i 0 /dev/sda1
```

> Setting interval between checks to 0 seconds

and

#### Disk mount count check

```
sudo tune2fs -c 0 /dev/sda1
```

> Setting maximal mount count to -1

---

The above two settings proved to be crucial, the disk check has finally been induced as I am no longer greeted with the mentioned message.

---

Useful reading: https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs